# Selectively display or hide button in the tree view in OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have placed the buttons (icon is green arrow) in the treeview. I want to show a button only if the record has a Bill of Material (BOM). I do have logic how to find out that, but don't know how to selectively display or hide a button.

Also, the display or hide button action should be triggered when the view is loaded. How I can do that since there is no view_on_load event like in Visual Basic for instance?

Here is the tree view:

[image]

Here is how the buttons are defined in XML file:

```
<!-- mrp_bom -->
        <record id="adamson_mrp_bom_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">adamson.mrp.bom.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Components']/field/tree[@string='Components']/field[@name='sequence']" position="before" >
                     <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" type="object" string="Go!" icon="gtk-go-forward" name="action_go"  />

                </xpath>
```

Here is the logic how to find if there is a BOM or not for particular product. Note bom_ids list which most likely will have only one value. This logic is used for button action but it can be used for deciding to show button or not.

```
class mrp_bom_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom.line'

    def action_go(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        bom_obj = self.pool.get('mrp.bom')

        for bom_line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if bom_line.product_id.default_code > '300':
                bom_ids = bom_obj.search(cr, uid, [('product_id', '=', bom_line.product_id.id)], context=context)
                if bom_ids:
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use attrs for example

```
attrs="{'invisible':[('selection_field_name','=','value')]}"
```

Note: we need to give value which is store in database.

try this,

```
<xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Components']/field/tree[@string='Components']/field[@name='sequence']" position="before" >
    <button class="oe_inline oe_stat_button" type="object" string="Go!" icon="gtk-go-forward" name="action_go" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','=','normal')]}"  />
</xpath>
```

Comment: I am not sure how to select 'selection_field_name'. For that reason I have updated my question with logic code. If you can give me example it would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: may i know from which condition field you want to hide/show button ?

Comment: In code I have bom_ids list which is indicator if that particular product has a Bill of Material (BOM). This list, most likely, will have only one element. If the list is empty then make button invisible. If bom_ids list has an element, then show the button.

Comment: bom_ids is not store in the database so we can't achieve on these way. you need to do something like add a boolean field on object and make it default false. Now in your code, if bom_ids have value than make it true otherwise false. on button hide/show, based on boolean field. hope you get idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea!! I got the idea, but I am very new to OpenERP and Python. Can you please give a code example: 1) How to add a boolean field to an object (I have a vague idea how to do that, but not sure). 2) How would you assign value to that field in code. Your help is so much appreciated.